# OpenGL: Weird transparency blending result

Tags: opengl, alphablending

I'm working on creating a transparent GUI in OpenGL, and am trying to get text rendered over some semi-transparent quads, but the results are odd.

If I render the text by itself, with nothing behind it, it looks fine:

[image: Text without transparent background]

However, if I render a semi-transparent quad behind it (rendering the quad before rendering the text), I get this:

[image: Text with transparent background]

I have blending set to (GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA). The font texture is an all-white texture with the character shapes in the alpha channel.

Do I need to be doing something special when performing alpha-transparency over an existing layer of transparency? Or is there something else I need to check?

Comment: Are you sure the alpha is zero around each letter?

Comment: +1 to @Nicol Bolas' suggestion. For instance, your source image might be alright, but your image loader could be screwing things up.

Answer (score 0):

The alpha value of your font texture seems to be off. It should be 0 for texels that you want to be invisible and 1 (or 255 in bytes) for visible texels. You should check the texture and make sure alpha values are correct.

Instead of alpha blending, you can use alpha testing. This will completely get rid of fragments, that have a alpha value below a certain threshold and is often much faster than blending.

```
glDisbale(GL_BLEND);    
glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);
glAlphaFunc(GL_GREATER, 0.96f); // Or some fitting threshold for your texture
```

This might work even if your texture's alpha is off in some places, but doesn't look like it is the case here, as the 's' and 't' seem to have a low alpha in places where it should be 1.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses. There was nothing wrong with my font texture, but your suggestions led me to try a few other things. Turns out the problem wasn't the transparency at all. There was a problem with rendering the background quad, which caused it to also render the text quads, but using the background texture. Bah...